# Can I point my +1 button to a Google+ photo?

Tags: google-plus, photo, google-plus-one

I have uploaded photos inside of Google+ and they received some +1. I also show the same photos on my personal website with a +1 button on each photo page. Right now, the +1 button on my site has an independent counter value. I know that I can specify a custom URL with the `data-href` attribute on the +1 button code, but it doesn't have any effect. Can I make my +1 button use the same counter as the uploaded photo?

Comment: You could use [embedded posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/), there is design constraint but +1s on the post would count on G+.

Comment: Not an option for me. The whole point of my photography website is its unique design. Embedding external anything just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't - the external URL and the photo +1 count are tracked separately.